# Hbase: execute multiple shell commands in one shot

Tags: hbase

I have to delete multiple rows in HBase based on key, I did a script like this :

```sh
deleteall 'mytable:myscheme', 'mykey'
deleteall 'mytable1:myscheme', 'mykey1'
deleteall 'mytable2:myscheme', 'mykey2'
deleteall 'mytable3:myscheme', 'mykey3'
deleteall 'mytable4:myscheme', 'mykey4'
```

I now use `hbase shell` to execute them one by one which is very tiring, I wonder if there is some way to execute all in one time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to store all those commands in a text file and apply them all together in one call.

Your `deleteall.txt`:

```
deleteall 'mytable:myscheme', 'mykey'
deleteall 'mytable1:myscheme', 'mykey1'
deleteall 'mytable2:myscheme', 'mykey2'
deleteall 'mytable3:myscheme', 'mykey3'
deleteall 'mytable4:myscheme', 'mykey4'
exit // add this line if you want to exit hbase shell at the end
```

Then run in it the shell

```
hbase shell < deleteall.txt
```

If you want your logs to be stored in a file instead of popping up on your terminal, you could use

```
hbase shell < deleteall.txt > myLog.log
```